# Understanding Networking Issue Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a server setup where I've bonded 4 interfaces (`bond1`) and connected this to a physical switch. I have added this `bond1` to an OVS switch `ovsbr1` with VM's attached to `ovsbr`.

It seems there was a change in how Ubuntu/debian handles dummy interfaces in 18.04. Previously I configured a dummy interface writing `dummy` to `/etc/modules-load.d/dummy.conf` and  `options dummy numdummies=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/dummy.conf`. This worked rather well and all I had to do then is configure the ip address.

However, this doesn't work well with 18.04. I can see the dummy module loaded using `lsmod` but I don't have any connectivity even on a different interface (I have a regular ethernet nic (ens3) also configure on the vm). Running tcpdump shows I can see traffic on `bond1` but for some reason, I am unable to connect outside the vm.

I read somewhere that removing the comment for the line `options dummy numdummies=0`, in `/lib/modprobe.d/systemd.conf` restores connectivity. There are multiple ways to address this which I am currently exploring but any insight into why I can see traffic but can't ping or connect to the external traffic would be appreciated.